# Submit a html form without submit button

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

I'm making a student details html page.I have a student details in a table and if their supervisor has been not selected, a supervisor drop down should appear in supervisor column.if they have selected their supervisor previously drop down will not appear and the supervisor's name will show. My problem is how to display only a drop down within a form element without submit button and as soon as select an option it should assign into a POST method.I'm using PHP OOP concepts.This is details table

```
if(isset($_SESSION['student'])){
$student=unserialize($_SESSION['student']);
echo "<div class=container>";
echo "<div class=details>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Student Name</td>";
echo "<td>".$student->getStudentName()." ".$student->getStudentSurname()."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<td>Supervisor</td>>";
echo "<td>";
if($student->getSupervisor()!=null){
    $student->selectSupervisor();
}else{
    $student->getSupervisor();
}
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

This is Student class

```
public function setSupervisor()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['supervisor'])){
            $this->supervisor = $_POST['supervisor'];
        }

    }

    //Select Supervisor function
    function selectSupervisor(){
        echo "<form action='Supervisee.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<select name='supervisor'>";
        $query = $handler->query("SELECT Lecturer_name FROM lecturer");
        while($row = $query->fetch()){
            echo "<option value='".$row['Lecturer_name']."'>".$row['Lecturer_name']."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

Comment: @mondieki - it is AN html form - and you forgot the stray bracket

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.corrected them

Comment: You have errors in the HTML that might require some looking into. In line 10, you are echoing a `>` in between two table cells and in line 22, and extra `</table>`.

Comment: noticed and thank you @MrLister